# Strange behavior of strsplit() in R?

Tags: r, strsplit

I would like to split the string `x = "a,b,"` (comma at the last place) into the vector `c("a","b","")` using *strsplit()*.

The result is:

```
>strsplit(x,',')
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"
```

I would like the have the third component (empty string or NULL).

The function `read.csv(x)` can manage that, but still I think that `strsplit()` should behave as I expected. Python gives `c("a","b","")`.

Maybe there is some option of `strsplit()` I do not know?

Comment: You can get your desired result with  
 `x <- stringr::str_pad("a,b,", 5, "right"); strsplit(x, ",| ")[[1]]`.  But yeah, that's how `strsplit` works.

Comment: You could use `str_split_fixed(x, ",", 3)` from `stringr`

Answer (score 8):

That's how it works and is documented in help(strsplit):

> ```
>  Note that this means that if there is a match at the beginning of
>  a (non-empty) string, the first element of the output is ‘""’, but
>  if there is a match at the end of the string, the output is the
>  same as with the match removed.
> ```

You might want to use `str_split` from the `stringr` package:

```
> require(stringr)
> str_split("a,b,",",")
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "" 

> str_split("a,b",",")
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b"

> str_split(",a,b",",")
[[1]]
[1] ""  "a" "b"

> str_split(",a,b,,,",",")
[[1]]
[1] ""  "a" "b" ""  ""  ""
```