# R strsplit keep last empty element as empty string

Tags: r, strsplit

R's `strsplit` drops the last element if "empty" (example 2) but not when occurring first (example 3) or in the middle of the vector to split (example 4).

```
> unlist(strsplit(x = "1,4", split = ",")) #Example 1
[1] "1" "4"
> unlist(strsplit(x = ",4", split = ",")) #Example 2
[1] ""  "4"
> unlist(strsplit(x = "1,", split = ",")) #Example 3
[1] "1"
> unlist(strsplit(x = "1,,,4", split = ",")) #Example 4
[1] "1" ""  ""  "4"
```

Is there a way to parse strings that allows keeping the last element if empty after split :

```
> strmagic(x = "1,", split = ",") #strmagic being the wanted function
[1] "1" ""
```

A solution with other packages is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077285/strange-behavior-of-strsplit-in-r?rq=1) (is seems). Can it be done in base R?

**UPDATE**

Will adding a filler element be necessary ed then a la:

```
strmagic <- function(v, sep)lapply(v, function(x)head(unlist(strsplit(paste(x, "-", sep = sep), split = sep)), -1))
```

Comment: You can add a `,` at the end of `x` when no comma ending the string but not really efficient, use `stringr`

Answer (score 1):

Weird.  This works but is not the most efficient.  ZAQ is just a set of random characters

```
sp <- function( X ){
    X <- paste0( X, "ZAQ" )
    X <- unlist(strsplit(x = X, split = ","))
    X <- gsub( "ZAQ" ,"" ,X) 
    X
}
sp("1,4")
sp(",4")
sp("1,")
sp("1,,,4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the stringr package. For me it works as I expected!

```
example1 <- "1,4"
example2 <- ",4"
example3 <- "1,"

unlist(stringr::str_split(example1,","))
unlist(stringr::str_split(example2,","))
unlist(stringr::str_split(example3,","))
```

Answer (score -1):

```r
strmagic <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(sub(",$", ",,", x), split = ","))
```

`strsplit` does not recognize the "empty" last element.  `sub(",$", ",,", x)` appends an additional comma to `x` if the last character in `x` is a comma, solving the problem.

Comment: Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question.