# How do I split a string by a character without ignoring trailing split-characters?

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a string similar to the following

```
my_string <- "apple,banana,orange,"
```

And I want to split by `,` to produce the output:

```
list(c('apple', 'banana', 'orange', ""))
```

I thought strsplit would accomplish this but it treats the trailing ',' like it doesn't exist

```r
my_string <- "apple,banana,orange,"

strsplit(my_string, split = ',')
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "apple"  "banana" "orange"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

What is the simplest approach to achieve the desired output?

Some more test cases with example strings and desired outputs

```
string1 = "apple,banana,orange,"
output1 = list(c('apple', 'banana', 'orange', ''))

string2 =  "apple,banana,orange,pear"
output2 = list(c('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'))

string3 =  ",apple,banana,orange"
output3 = list(c('', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange'))

## Examples of non-comma separated strings
# '|' separator
string4 =  "|apple|banana|orange|"
output4 = list(c('', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange', ''))

# 'x' separator
string5 =  "xapplexbananaxorangex"
output5 = list(c('', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange', ''))
```

EDIT:

Ideally solution should generalize to any splitting character

Would also prefer a base-R solution (although do still link any packages which supply this functionality since their source code might be useful to look through!)

Comment: I can't find anything, but I'm sure this is a dupe. Check out `stringi::stri_split_fixed`

Comment: It's a diversion from `strsplit`, but `scan(text=my_string, sep=",", what="")` works as intended.

Comment: @thelatemail I quite like your scan solution, Its great as quick baseR workaround. Needs to be sat in an apply function to get it working sensibly on vectors but otherwise is a very neat trick

Comment: scan is a good solution, just wrap it into a function, then use lapply as you wish.

Comment: @JosephWood Found it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077285/strange-behavior-of-strsplit-in-r Although, since this question is now higher scored and has more answers, maybe the older question should be marked a duplicate of *this* one.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Just marked the other question as a dupe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pasting another separator at the end should allow `strsplit` to function as intended.
Otherwise, you could fall back to using the `scan` function, which underpins the `read.csv/table` functions:

```
strsplit(paste0(string1, ","), ",")
##[[1]]
##[1] "apple"  "banana" "orange" ""
```

Generalisably taking into account regex replacement:

```
L <- list(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5)
mapply(
    function(x,s) strsplit(paste0(x, gsub("\\\\", "", s)), split=s),
    L,
    c(",", ",", ",", "\\|", "x")
)

##[[1]]
##[1] "apple"  "banana" "orange" ""      
##
##[[2]]
##[1] "apple"  "banana" "orange" "pear"  
##
##[[3]]
##[1] ""       "apple"  "banana" "orange"
##
##[[4]]
##[1] ""       "apple"  "banana" "orange" ""      
##
##[[5]]
##[1] ""       "apple"  "banana" "orange" ""
```

`scan` option:

```
scan(text=string1, sep=",", what="")
##Read 4 items
##[1] "apple"  "banana" "orange" ""
```

Generalising:

```
mapply(
    function(x,s) scan(text=x, sep=s, what=""),
    L,
    c(",", ",", ",", "|", "x")
)
```

Comment: I think `scan` is the cheapest base R workaround for this question, cheers!

Comment: Marking as answer as meets all criteria (base R implementation, outputs exactly as described in question). For future reference,  the answer by ThomasIsCoding describes an alternative baseR solution thats also really nice. Anyone not requiring a baseR implementation should see GuedesBF answer for a simple solution using stringr

Answer (score 14):

## Why `strsplit` Doesn't Give Desired Output?

When you type `?strsplit`, you will read the following statement

> Note that this means that if there is a match at the beginning of a
> (non-empty) string, the first element of the output is "", but if
> there is a match at the end of the string, the output is the same as
> with the match removed.

That is the reason you don't see the trailing `""` when you use `strsplit`.

Below are some demonstrations

```
> strsplit("apple,banana,orange,", ",")
[[1]]
[1] "apple"  "banana" "orange"


> strsplit(",apple,banana,orange,", ",")
[[1]]
[1] ""       "apple"  "banana" "orange"


> strsplit(",apple,banana,orange", ",")
[[1]]
[1] ""       "apple"  "banana" "orange"


> strsplit("apple,banana,orange", ",")
[[1]]
[1] "apple"  "banana" "orange"
```

---

## A Base R Workaround

If you want to make a coding practice, one base R option can be defining a custom function (recursion) like below

```
f <- function(x, sep = ",") {
  pat <- sprintf("^(.*?)%s.*", sep)
  s1 <- sub(pat, "\\1", x)
  s2 <- sub(paste0("^.*?", sep), "", x)
  if (s2 == x) {
    return(x)
  }
  c(s1, Recall(s2, sep))
}
```

or a variant with `substr` + `regexpr`

```
f <- function(x, sep = ",") {
  idx <- regexpr(sep, x)
  s1 <- substr(x, 1, idx - 1)
  s2 <- substr(x, idx + 1, nchar(x))
  if (s2 == x) {
    return(x)
  }
  c(s1, Recall(s2, sep))
}
```

such that

```
> f("apple,banana,orange,")
[1] "apple"  "banana" "orange" ""

> f(",apple,banana,orange,")
[1] ""       "apple"  "banana" "orange" ""      

> f(",apple,banana,orange")
[1] ""       "apple"  "banana" "orange"

> f("apple,banana,orange")
[1] "apple"  "banana" "orange"
```

Answer (score 13):

Use stringr

```r
library(stringr)

str_split(my_string, ",")

[[1]]
[1] "apple"  "banana" "orange" ""
```

Comment: This works (+1), but interestingly enough, still doesn't work for `strsplit`, as opposed to `stringr::str_split`.

Comment: which is expected `## Note that final empty strings are not produced`

Comment: I think this answer can be simplified to just using `stringr::str_split()` since it handles leading and trailing strings, `stringr::str_split(",apple,banana,orange,", pattern = ",")`

Comment: This is a great solution and is likely to be useful for future viewers. Only reason reason it is not marked as the answer is due to the preference for a base-R solution

Comment: If simplicity is desired, `stringr::str_split_1(my_string, ",")` will return a `character vector` instead of of a `list`: `[1] "apple"  "banana" "orange" ""`.

Comment: Yes, that is true, Adriano, but the OP included lists as the desired outputs

Comment: The thing that makes this the best solution is that it uses a cpp vectorized function in the backend. If R was just base-R then it wouldn't be worth using in 2023. The thing that makes R good is all the extra libraries available.

Comment: Agreed, @DeanMacGregor. The tidyverse (as a major example) is so consistent, useful, and efficient, I see little reason for the "just base R" questions we see now and then. I believe some may ask for base R answers because of some misconception of base R as "faster" or "more efficient" than tidyverse-based answers, which is usually not true. I should acknowledge that the 'avoid dependencies` argument is valid though. We are talking about a huge metapackage

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I agree that for most people reading this, the tidyyverse solution will be the most useful answer (hence i point to it in a comment on the marked solution). But for me its simply an 'avoid dependencies' issue (since I do a lot of package-dev). It is hard to know whether taking on the dependency is worth it unless you see the base R solution first, which is why I personally like specifying base-R in the question :)